# Unbiased estimator for a parameter from a transformed distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expected-value, unbiased-estimator

I am solving an exercise in which I have to show that a certain estimator is unbiased for a given parameter. However, after a couple lines of computation I got stuck in the following scenario:

$$
\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}) = -c \cdot \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)}\right),
$$

such that $X_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}\left(p = \exp\left(-\frac{c}{\theta}\right)\right)$, for some positive constant $c$. Since I am working with non-linear transformations of $X_i$, I am not sure how to deal with the expectation. At the end of the day, I would like to show that $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}) = \theta$.

If I just use the definition of $\mathbb{E}(\cdot)$, with the fact that $Y = \sum_{i = i}^{n}X_i \sim \text{Binomial}\left(n, \exp\left(-\frac{c}{\theta}\right)\right)$, I get

$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(\frac{Y}{n}\right)}\right) = \sum_{y = 0}^{n} {n \choose y} \left(\exp\left(-\frac{c}{\theta}\right)\right)^{y} \left(1- \exp\left(-\frac{c}{\theta}\right)\right)^{n - y} \frac{1}{\ln\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)},
$$

which does not help me either.

Comment: Have you considered what happens when $y=0$ or $y=n$?

Comment: @JimB, I am not quite sure what you referring to, but I noticed that for $y = n$ I get $\ln(1) = 0$ in the denominator, which is undefined. But I am not sure what could be wrong. Considering just the first paragraph of my question, is it possible to get a different path towards a solution?

Comment: For a statistic to be unbiased, the mean has to exist.  Your current definition gives $1/-\infty$ when $y=0$ (which you might want to define as zero) and undefined when $y=1$ (because you're dividing by zero).  The point is that you'll need to adjust your definition if you want an unbiased statistic or state that $E(\hat{\theta})$ doesn't exist.  Or condition on $y<n$.